# Check if array of Dates are adjacent ordered months

Tags: ruby, date

I have an array of Dates. I need to check if it follows a month sequence, e.g.:

```
[Mar 2010, Apr 2010, May 2010, Jun 2010, ..., Jan 2012]
```

Since a Date object should have day, month and year, I want to ignore the day, and just worry about month and year.

I want to get `true` if there are no months "missing" on the sequence. In other words, after April or the vector ends, or I have a May; after a May either the vector ends or there is a June.

I want to get `false` if the months are not ordered correctly (from older to newer) or if there are months missing.

I can easily check if the dates are ordered by using the "<" operator. But I'm not sure how to check if there are missing months. How can I do that?

Comment: *are not ordered correctly* means ?

Comment: They should be ordered from oldest to newer. Sorry :)

Comment: Be consistent. What is the difference between "array", "sequence", and "vector"? Also, I cannot parse your sentence starting with "In other words ...". What do you want to do with duplicate months?

Comment: Your emphasis on "month" makes your question sound like "April 2010" may count as the next month for "March 2014". This does not look like what you want, so your question is misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way

```
require 'date'
>> dates 
=> ["Nov 2010", "Dec 2010", "Jan 2011"]

>> date_objs = dates.map{|d| Date.parse d }
=> [#<Date: 2010-03-01 ((2455257j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)...]

>> date_objs.each_cons(2).all?{|d1, d2| d1.next_month == d2 }
=> true
```

This handles missing months as well:

```
>> dates = ["Nov 2010", "Dec 2010", "Feb 2011"]
>> date_objs = dates.map{|d| Date.parse(d) }
>> date_objs.each_cons(2).all?{|d1, d2| d1.next_month == d2 }
=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'date'
ar =["Mar 2010","Apr 2010", "May 2010", "Jun 2010"]
p ar.map{|d| Date.parse(d)}.each_cons(2).all?{|(d1,d2)| (d1 >> 1) == d2} #=> true
```